# Motion-Mmal: I want to disable live stream capabilities

Tags: raspbian, camera, streaming-video, motion

I have a few questions about Motion-MMAL:
Sorry if these are noob questions.

1) I want to disable the live stream capability completely; however, i can only find information on how to keep the live stream local

2) If I do not visit the local address for the live stream, is it still technically uploading data and live streaming?

I am using Rpi B+, running on Raspbian.

Answer (score 4):

as per the comments in the motion.conf

```
# The mini-http server listens to this port for requests (default: 0 = disabled)
webcam_port 0
```

Motion will still monitor the frames on the camera, after all it is looking for motion. But with the webcam server disabled no data will be "served" anywhere.

Comment: Now it is called stream_port. Set it from 8081 to 0.